# Jenkins deployment to docker swarm by using Ansible

Tags: docker, jenkins, apache-zookeeper, consul, swarm

In my environment we are deploying to docker swarm from Jenkins by using Ansible, we scaled it by overlay network, using discovery services like Consul and Zookeeper,

My question is how we are scaling the nodes, how the consul know the key values, how we need to define the frame work of docker swarm